# how to reset filter on loading a collection in magento custom module

Tags: magento-1.8, grid, reset-filter

I have created a custom module in backend to display the search results of 'imei' in  admin grid.

1) below is the  home page to search imei.
[image]

2) search result page.

[image]

3) after searching i enter the value say for example 23 in imei text field search.
[image]

4)now i going back to home page and searching another value.

[image]

5)but now i get no records found, but there is records for that particular search.

[image]

since this happens, i have to reset filter on loading collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit grid.php file in your custom module,

By default,

```
public function __construct()
{
 parent::__construct();
 $this->setId('productsGrid');
 // This is the primary key of the database
 $this->setDefaultSort('id');
 $this->setDefaultDir('ASC');
 $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
 $this->setUseAjax(true);
}
```

Change the code to,

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setId('productsGrid');
    // This is the primary key of the database
    $this->setDefaultSort('id');
    $this->setDefaultDir('ASC');
    $this->setUseAjax(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your filter value base64_encoded to the corresponding controller. The filter value gets processed by `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::_prepareCollection()`.

The value is first decoded and then set in the session:

```
    $data = $this->helper('adminhtml')->prepareFilterString($filter);
    $this->_setFilterValues($data);
```

I would start instantiating the grid.js object. Take a look at the methods `doFilter()` and `resetFilter()`.