# Reset admin grid filter programmatically in magento

Tags: magento-1.8, reset-filter, grid

I want to reset the admin grid filter programatically in my custom module.

Comment: can you please explain me detail which type so I will help you.

Comment: Please refer this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/24596/how-to-reset-filter-on-loading-a-collection-in-magento-custom-module

Comment: did u understand that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit `grid.php` file in your custom module,

By default,

```
public function __construct()
{
  parent::__construct();
  $this->setId('productsGrid');
  // This is the primary key of the database
  $this->setDefaultSort('id'); 
  $this->setDefaultDir('ASC');
  $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
  $this->setUseAjax(true);
}
```

change the code to,

```
public function __construct()
{
  parent::__construct();
  $this->setId('productsGrid');
  // This is the primary key of the database
  $this->setDefaultSort('id'); 
  $this->setDefaultDir('ASC');
  $this->setSaveParametersInSession(false);
  $this->setUseAjax(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery / JavaScript to clear the field manually after every load of a collection.

Once the field is clear and a new value is entered it will search the whole collection again.

More specifically you can do the following steps:

- Get the grid table via selector
- Loop through all of the `<th>`'s
- Find the `<input>` tags and clear the `value` attribute

Answer (score 0):

The previous replies are not really replying to the question that is asking to reset the filters.
In my case, I didn't want to remove the ability to have the parameters into the session as this is a nice feature. I wanted to remove parameters ONLY if there are specific configurations in the URL that sends default data.

My approach was to remove data in the session directly.

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setId('gridId');
    $this->setDefaultSort('updated_at');
    $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
    $this->setUseAjax(true);
    $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);

    if ($default = $this->getRequest()->getParam('default')) {
        $defaultFilters = [];
        // add script to add your personalized filters here

        $sessionParamName = $this->getId() . $this->getVarNameFilter();
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setData($sessionParamName, '');
        $this->setDefaultFilter($defaultFilters);
    }
}
```